# Java Stack

Tags: java, строки

Разработать функцию преобразования однонаправленного кольца в стек. Элементы кольца – символьные строки.

Помогите пожалуйста с этой задачей. Объясните как это должно происходить, ибо я вообще не понимаю смысл в этой задаче.

Comment: Вы бы еще объяснили нам сирым что за коллекция такая "кольцо"...

Comment: Вот и я не знаю, скорей всего однонаправленный список

Comment: список это это как цепь, - каждый элемент связан с следующим и предыдущим. в одностороннем каждый элемент имеет ссылку на следующий элемент цепочки. в двустороннем на следующий и предыдущий. но цепь не станет замкнутой до тех пор пока вы не добавите ссылку последнему элементу на первый. посему ни одна реализация интерфейса list в java вам не подходит. пожалуй проще всего будет если вы пронаследуетесь от класса LinkedList. с другой стороны вам вообще не обязательно наследоватся от какого-либо базового класа java :) пишите свою реализацию а развернуть список в stack это детская задачка :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если под "кольцом" имеется ввиду направленный список `List` то тогда примерно так

```
List<String> stringsList=new ArrayList<String>(); //направленный список
// наполняем список случайными строками
Random rand=new Random();
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
   stringsList.add("MyString"+rand.nextInt()); 
//инициализируем стек строк
Stack<String> stack=new Stack<String>();
for(String s:stringsList)
    stack.push(s); //пихаем в стек
```

Как там бы ни было смысл простой. Берем коллекцию (какая бы она ни была), берем его итератор (правило обхода) и пихаем элементы в стек - `Stack.push()`

Comment: хм, спасибо, попробую рассмотреть, что-то еще поделать.

Comment: а где кольцо? Замыкание...

Comment: Только вот ArrayList это совсем не направленный список.

Comment: @Nofate - согласен, ArrayList это сортированный список

Answer (score 1):

Я, например, знаю кольцевой буфер, используемый в сетевой технике т.к. они очень хорошо справляются с потоковыми данными. Т.е. по своей сути это похоже на список, только замкнутый. Вы всегда знаете его размер, начало и конец. Начало в вашем случае неизменно, но может быть в любом месте буфера, а конец это указатель на элемент к которому вы будете добавлять очередное значение. При достижении своей максимальной длины буфер замыкается на первый элемент, причем как я уже писал это может быть даже не указатель на начало.

Так как у вас есть начальный и конечный указатели, делайте стек. Зная направление размещения элементов в буфере, переносите все с начала в конец. У вас может возникнуть одна проблема - если буфер полон или полностью пуст, указатели на начало и конец совпадают, а значит сложно узнать кто есть кто. Для этой проблемы один элемент оставляют пустым.

Comment: @Dex, похоже это единственный здесь разумный ответ.

    Для этой проблемы один элемент оставляют пустым.

если требуется я просто вместе с кольцевым буфером храню количество элементов в нем. При добавлении увеличиваю (если нет переполнения), при выборке уменьшаю.

--

Вообще задачка странная, недаром автор вопроса пишет:

    ибо я вообще не понимаю смысл в этой задаче.

Надо спрашивать автора задачи ...

Comment: @avp, тоже логичный ход кстати!

Answer (score 1):

Не думаю, что имеется ввиду использование JDK для решения данной задачи. По-моему, вам надо организовать связный список, который будет иметь форму кольца: последний элемент списка будет ссылаться на первый. Далее какая-то функция, например, doStack(String element) разрывает кольцо в указанном месте, просто удаляя ссылку на следующий элемент, тем самым преобразуя кольцо в стек.
Еще советую почитать про различные способы организации хранеиния данных: стэк, кольцо, очередь, дерево...
А пользователю **Barmaley** стоит получше изучить Java Collections.

Comment: @RomanoO Ню-ню...

Comment: что "ню-ню"